# Svelte passing number as prop

Tags: typescript, svelte

I am new to Svelte and I am trying to pass a number value as prop. Here is the code below.

```
<script lang="ts">
  import Infobox from "./Infobox.svelte";
</script>

<Infobox classCount=2 taskCount=6 />

<style></style>
```

```
<script lang="ts">
  export let taskCount: number;
  export let classCount: number;
</script>

<section>
  <div>{taskCount} Tasks</div>
  <div>Class {classCount}</div>
</section>

<style></style>
```

I am unable to pass the prop as a number and it is accepting only string like
`<Infobox classCount="2" taskCount="6" />`.

I am using typescript as well in this project.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The right way of passing prop value was using curly braces.

`<Infobox classCount={2} taskCount={6} />`

This solved the issue.